# Помогите с лёгкой программой

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Необходимо из числа вытащить все цифры по отдельности.

Извлекать цифры можно при помощи деления и вычисления остатка. Например, если исходное число — это X, то `A = X % 10;` поместит в переменную A последнюю цифру числа X. Аналогично, команда `X = X / 10;` отрежет от числа последнюю цифру. Извлекать цифры нужно, пока X не станет равным нулю.

Как это сделать на проге я не понимаю

Answer (score 5):

Так создаёте условный цикл, в котором условие выхода будет X==0, а остальное то вы написали. цифра A = X % 10, а удалить X = X / 10;

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace SimpleProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //исходное число
            int x = 5175;
            while (x != 0)
            {
                int a = x % 10;
                Console.WriteLine("Извлеченная цифра: {0}", a);
                x = x / 10;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```